# TypeScript foreach return

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this - looks like returning out of a foreach doesn't return out of the function containing the foreach loop, which may be an expectation from C# devs.

Just wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this:

```
example() {
    var forEachReturned;

    this.items.forEach(item => {
        if (true) {
            forEachReturned = true;
            return;
        }
    });

    if (forEachReturned) {
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff in case forEach has not returned
}
```

Comment: Spoilt by Linq and Lambdas ... ;)

Comment: FYI C#/.NET's `List<T>.ForEach()` would behave precisely the same way you're seeing here. JavaScript's `Array#forEach` is not quite analogous to C#'s `foreach` loop - one is a method and the other is a control structure.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The cleaner way would be to not use `.forEach`. It's almost never needed if you're using TypeScript or a modern version of JavaScript:

```
example() {
    for (let item of this.items) {
        if (item === 3) {
            return;
        }
    }      

    // Do stuff in case forEach has not returned
}
```

If the code inside your loop doesn't have any side-effects and you're just checking for a condition on each item, you could also use a functional approach with `.some`:

```
example() {
    if (this.items.some(item => item === 3)) {
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff in case we have not returned
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!! One side effect of a 'for' instead of 'foreach' array, is that in Angular 6 and TypeScript 2.9.2, it seems that under *certain* conditions, using 'for' loops with result in the current object within the array being undefined, whereas that issue does not come up with .forEach(). Any ideas?

Comment: @Ross The only situation where I can think of that happening is in the case of a sparse array, e.g. `let arr = [1,2,3,,,4,5,6]`. `forEach` and other array prototype methods (`map`, `filter`) will skip over the empty entries, but `for..of` will not.